# Render dynamic created components inside a specific DOM element

Tags: angular, dynamic, components

I have a parent component as below

```
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="row">
    <app-tile-render #tileRender [itemMasterId]="itemMasterId" [partName]="partName" [conditionIds]="conditionIds"
      [showViewIcon]="true"></app-tile-render>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is the renderer component where I am using `ng-template` to render the dynamically generated components

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-tile-render',
    template: `<ng-template tileHost>
    </ng-template>`
})
export class TileRenderComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() tiles: TileItem[] = [];
    @Input() itemMasterId: number;
    @Input() partName: string;
    @Input() conditionIds: any;
    @Input() showViewIcon: boolean;

    @ViewChild(TileDirective, { static: false }) tileHost!: TileDirective;

    constructor(public tileService: TileService,
        public componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        private renderer: Renderer2) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    loadComponent() {
        this.tiles = this.tileService.getTiles();

        const viewContainerRef = this.tileHost.viewContainerRef;
        viewContainerRef.clear();

        for (let i = 0; i < this.tiles.length; i++) {
            const tileItem = this.tiles[i];
            const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(tileItem.component);

            const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent<TileComponent>(componentFactory);
            componentRef.instance.itemMasterId = this.itemMasterId;
            componentRef.instance.partName = this.partName;
            componentRef.instance.conditionIds = this.conditionIds;
            componentRef.instance.showViewIcon = this.showViewIcon;
        }
    }
}
```

`tile.service.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class TileService {
    @Input() itemMasterId: any;
    getTiles() {
        return [
            new TileItem(
                CommonPurchaseOrderListComponent
            ),
            new TileItem(
                CommonRepairOrderListComponent
            ), new TileItem(
                CommonSalesOrderListComponent
            )
        ];
    }
}
```

But here the issue is that it renders all the components (tiles) at once as below:

[image]

Instead of that I want to render all the component inside each bootstrap column so that it looks in a proper sequence.

like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        want to display each dynamic generated component here..............
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What it's the response of this.tileService.getTiles()? remember that "services return observables, you subscribe in components"

Comment: @Eliseo I have added the service class.. It will just return the component reference itself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `loadComponent` function you can initialize a new constant, which will be holding the columns:

```
const rowDiv = this.renderer.createElement('div');
this.renderer.addClass(rowDiv, 'row');
```

Then, inside a for loop, after You initialize constant `componentRef` You should trigger a new function, which will hold a reference to the rowDiv and also a componentRef, to later on nest it inside wrapping `<div class="col-md-4"></div>`

```
const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent<TileComponent>(componentFactory);
this.createColumnForComponent(rowDiv, componentRef);
```

Function createColumnForComponent:

```
  private createColumnForComponent(
    componentRef: ComponentRef<any>,
    rowDiv: HTMLElement
  ) {
    // setup a div with class col-md-4
    const columnDiv: HTMLElement = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    this.renderer.addClass(columnDiv, 'col-md-4');
    const componentElement: HTMLElement = componentRef.location.nativeElement;
    // append component to column
    this.renderer.appendChild(columnDiv, componentElement);
    // append column to row
    this.renderer.appendChild(rowDiv, columnDiv);
  }
```

After that function our rowDiv is filled with the columns. We need to make use of it, so we trigger it once, after the for loop execution:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.tiles.length; i++) {
...
}
this.createRowForColumns(viewContainerRef, rowDiv);
```

Function createRowForColumns:

```
  private createRowForColumns(
    viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    rowDiv: HTMLElement
  ) {
    // append row to our selector
    this.renderer.appendChild(
      viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement.parentNode,
      rowDiv
    );
```

In following code I made a use of [renderer](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) but You could also follow more native approach, like:

```
columnDiv.appendChild(componentElement);
columnDiv.classList.add('col-md-4');
```